# How to update all field of one java object with the values from another one?

Tags: java, lombok

Assume the following class:

```
public class TestClass {
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
    String attr3;
}
```

and a client code like:

```
final TestClass testClassA = new TestClass();
testClassA.attr1 = "1";
testClassA.attr1 = "2";
testClassA.attr1 = "3";

final TestClass testClassB = new TestClass();
```

I would like to find way/method that updates `testClassB` with all the values of `testClassA`.

```
testClassB.updateAll(testClassA)
```

One such solution would be:

```
public void updateAll(TestClass testClass) {
    this.attr1 = testClass.attr1;
    this.attr2 = testClass.attr2;
    this.attr3 = testClass.attr3;
}
```

Now, here comes the thing: I would like to not have to write this method manually for it to be less resilient when e.g. a new attribute is added. In this case I might forget to add it to the update-method.

The solution does not need to assign the values directly, in fact I'd prefer it to call setter methods.

It is also possible for me to use any 3rd party frameworks out there like Lombok. I am looking for something like the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, however I need the new object to be *updated* and not created.

So something like a `@RequiredArgsSetter` or a `Object.updateInto(Object1 o, Object2 o)` method, but again, it should not create a new object but simply update all the fields of an existing object.

Bonus points, if it is somehow possible to annotate the fields which should be included or excluded from being set.

Comment: why dont you clone the object instead?

Comment: As I said, I want it to update an existing object not create a new one.

Comment: You could do this with reflection...you could query the metadata for the class involved to find out what attributes it contains, and use that data to copy each variable programatically.  I do not know of an existing library that will do this.  I would suggest that your object store its fields in a single Map value.  You could write getters and setters that referenced the Map, and so you wouldn't know the difference there.  But when copying the object, you could just copy the map and you'd get whatever values are stored in it.

Comment: Right, this is the kind of solution I also had in mind, but I was wondering if there is anything existent already in the JDK or other libraries that do this.

Comment: Another approach would be to create the byte-code for such a setter, like what Lombok does with the @RequiredArgsConstructor....but I don't know a framework that has such an annotation either.

Comment: How often are you going to be adding fields to your. objects?  I wonder if it's worth all of this work and obfuscation just so that you don't have to remember to add a few extra assignment statements to your class defs.  This is especially true if you don't really want to copy all of your fields, but rather have that be configurable.  Now you're talking about a lot of extra stuff.  I don't have a problem with what you're looking to do.  I'm just asking if it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Good question, I don't know for sure yet either but those mistakes of forgetting to include a field in the manual update method are often hard to detect because there is no warning/error at compile time. I am taking the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` as a model/example and don't consider it to be a lot of work. There you can also annotate fields with something like `@Exclude` which I find very handy. Also, the class we are talking about is rather huge and has more than 20 or 30 attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question interesting and decided to try it out. Here is a solution using reflection. It looks for fields that match by name and type and which are not excluded by annotation, then sets the values of any matching fields.

Disclaimer: I haven't thoroughly tested this, only lightly. It may need some work. It also doesn't use setter methods but instead just sets the field value.

Attribute copying method:

```
public class AttrCopy {

    public void copyAttributes(Object from, Object to) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Field> toFieldNameMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Field f : to.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            toFieldNameMap.put(f.getName(), f);
        }
        for(Field f : from.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Field ff = toFieldNameMap.get(f.getName());
            f.setAccessible(true);
            boolean include = f.getDeclaredAnnotation(AttrCopyExclude.class) == null;
            if(include && ff != null && ff.getType().equals(f.getType())) {
                ff.setAccessible(true);
                ff.set(to, f.get(from));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Annotation to exclude fields:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AttrCopyExclude {
}
```

Test classes:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String attribute1;
    private int attribute2;
    private int attribute3;
    private String attribute4;
    private String attribute5;

    // toString()
}

public class ClassB {
    private String attribute1;
    private int attribute2;
    private String attribute3;
    @AttrCopyExclude
    private String attribute4;
    private String attribute6;

    // toString()
}
```

Test code:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA("aaa", 123, 456, "ddd", "eee");
        ClassB classB = new ClassB("111", 789, "333", "444", "555");

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println(classA);
        System.out.println(classB);

        new AttrCopy().copyAttributes(classB, classA);

        System.out.println("After copy A -> B");
        System.out.println(classA);
        System.out.println(classB);
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
Before
ClassA{attribute1='aaa', attribute2=123, attribute3=456, attribute4='ddd', attribute5='eee'}
ClassB{attribute1='111', attribute2=789, attribute3='333', attribute4='444', attribute6='555'}
After copy B -> A
ClassA{attribute1='111', attribute2=789, attribute3=456, attribute4='ddd', attribute5='eee'}
ClassB{attribute1='111', attribute2=789, attribute3='333', attribute4='444', attribute6='555'}
```

Attributes 1 and 2 are copied. 3 is excluded as type does not match. 4 is excluded by annotation. The last is excluded as the name doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort! This solution does indeed seem like it would do the trick, even though there are probably still some edge cases we haven't thought about yet ;-). I won't mark it as accepted as it requires manual reflection code (which I'd rather stay away from) but if there are no other solution, I'll try it out on Monday for our code. Thanks you!

Comment: @schrobe Fair enough :) I almost want to build it into a lib and push it to Maven central but then I'd need to test it completely and that feels like too much work. :D

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) to copy between java object. Great example [here](https://reflectoring.io/java-mapping-with-mapstruct/)